# Jekyll generates, but doesn't serve after upgrading

Tags: console, jekyll

Jekyll doesn’t server after updating my Mac to El Capitan and Jekyll itself any more. While it appears that it actually is generating the site, there is no indication that it would listen to some port in the console.

There’s no other thing running on the same port.

Here’s what I did:

1. Upgraded to El Capitan
2. After receiving “unknown command” when I typed in “jekyll” into the console I did

   ```
   sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin GEM_NAME_HERE
   ```

like suggested here (https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1768)

3. Updated Jekyll

I’m unfortunately not able to tell if it was actually the OS update or the Jekyll update that caused this.

Does anyone have a hint?

My Jekyll-Version is 2.5.3.